# Make Sublime Text plugin autocompletions work properly

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3, sublimetext4

I think I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what exactly.

What I need: in Sublime Text, I wish autocomplete function to suggest me right things.
For example, after typing "request." I expect to see "query, url, method, headers" but NOT "for, :env, proto". After typing "Math." I expect to see "round, floor..." but not "background, headers, console"

I have tried installing plugins like Tern JS, JSAutocomplete, but this seem not do anything.

Suppose I have installed an autocomplete plugin and it appears under Preferences -> Package Settings -> Plugin Name. How do i know autocomplete is going from that plugin and not from other one? How to change autocomplete source?

This all goes to versions 3 and 4